# How to turn a column of strings into a list of factors, filtering values with regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with a column (A) that contains strings such that each word is separated by a comma (still one string).

```
   Df
   A                              B           etc.
   "String1, String2, etc."      ...          etc.
```

I want to

1. Turn the observations in column A into a list. The list will contain elements string 1, string 2 etc.
2. I want to remove all strings that are not 8 characters long, start with 4 numbers and end with 4 digits (I already have the Regex for that)
3. I want to turn all the strings into factors

The end product should look like this

```
   Df
   A                              B           etc.
   [String1, String2, etc]       ...          etc.
```

Doing some testing, I've realised a combination of strsplit() and str_subset fulfills requirements 1 and 2

```
   var = "ABCD1234, ABCDEFGH"
   var = str_split(var, ", ")
   var = str_subset(var, "^[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{4}$")
   # Var = list("ABCD1234")
```

But I'm having trouble applying this to a dataframe column. So far, this has not worked

```
    df = df %>% mutate(
         A = strsplit(A, split = ", ")
         A = case_when(
             TRUE ~ str_subset(A, "^[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{4}$")
             )
         )
```

Could someone help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can combine the two steps by first splitting the string on `", "` and then use `str_subset` to get the strings which follow a pattern.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(new = str_split(A, ", "), 
         new = map(new, str_subset, pattern = "^[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{4}$"))

#                   A                new
#1 ABCD1234, ABCDEFGH           ABCD1234
#2    AQD12345, AQWE1                   
#3 ABCD1234, ABCD5678 ABCD1234, ABCD5678
```

---

We can do this in base R, as well

```
df$new <- lapply(strsplit(df$A, ", "), grep, 
                 pattern = "^[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{4}$", value = TRUE)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("ABCD1234, ABCDEFGH", "AQD12345, AQWE1", 
                       "ABCD1234, ABCD5678"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you know how to now change the strings into factors? E.g. ["String1", "String2"] --> [String1, String2]. Thanks

Comment: @PatWong you can do `df %>%
  mutate(new = str_split(A, ", "), 
         new = map(new, ~factor(str_subset(., "^[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{4}$"))))`